# Change width of Slider only by right C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to stretch my slider only on the right side of it. I attached to the script the Slider and its 'Fill Area'. I tried changing sizeDelta but it stretches to both ways...

```
public Slider healthSlider;
public GameObject healthRect;

void Update () {
    healthRect.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().sizeDelta += Vector2.right * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

The anchors are set to top-left for the Slider and top-stretch for the 'Fill Area'
Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use the `RectTransform`'s [`SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge`](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/ScriptReference/RectTransform.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge.html) method. Your code might look like this:

```
public Slider healthSlider;
public GameObject healthRect;
private float sliderSize = 100;

void Update ()
{
    healthRect.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left, 0, sliderSize);
    sliderSize += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

This will keep the slider alligned to the left while 'scaling' it out to the right. The second parameter lets you position where the left side of the slider should be relative to it's parent.

Note: calling `GetComponent` in the update function is inefficient you should cache a reference to the `RectTransform` at `Start` and then use that like so:

```
public Slider healthSlider;
public GameObject healthRect;
private float sliderSize = 100;
private RectTransform healthRectTransform;

void Start()
{
    healthRectTransform = healthRect.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

void Update ()
{
    healthRectTransform.SetInsetAndSizeFromParentEdge(RectTransform.Edge.Left, 0, sliderSize);
    sliderSize += Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Doing it this way means that you only have to call `GetComponent` once in the `Start` function which is far more efficient.

Note Note: If you are just assigning the `healthRect` Gameobject in the inspector and only using it to get it's `RectTransform` component then you can delete this variable and just assign the `healthRectTransform` field in the inspector and skip out the part in the `Start` method.

Comment: Thank you ! Nevertheless iI don't understand why do we have to 'cache' the GetComponent ?

Comment: If you don't, the you are calling 'GetComponent` every frame. This means you are searching the entire gameObject for the component you want *every frame*. Caching a reference gets the component once and then uses the local member variable instead which avoids looking it up every time . If you need more info the you can google it. There are millions of blogs/forum threads on it. :)